# How do I reference a nested object or arrays path/location using a variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have some data consisting of objects and array within an object as such:

```
let productDataObj = {
  prodType1: {
    keyTermsArr: [],
    frequencyObj: {},
    ratingObj: {}
  },
  prodType2: {
    keyTermsArr: [],
    frequencyObj: {},
    ratingObj: {}
  }
};
```

I have some code that pushes to each of these nested objects and arrays. I want to save the 'reference'(?) to each of these objects/arrays as a variable so I don't have to re-write code, eg:

```
let keyTermsArrRef;
let frequencyRef;
let ratingRef;

for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if (prodType[i] == 1) {
        keyTermsArrRef = productDataObj.prodType1.keyTermsArr;
        frequencyRef = productDataObj.prodType1.frequencyObj;
        ratingRef = productDataObj.prodType1.ratingObj;
    }
    else if (prodType[i] == 2) {
        keyTermsArrRef = productDataObj.prodType2.keyTermsArr;
        frequencyRef = productDataObj.prodType2.frequencyObj;
        ratingRef = productDataObj.prodType2.ratingObj;
    }

    // Do some stuff with/push to keyTermsArrRef, frequencyRef and ratingRef
```

The problem is, of course, my data is not stored being in the nested arrays but simply in the 3 variables I created to reference the location of the nested arrays.

Does anyone know a way I can use a variable to reference the 'paths' to these nested arrays and objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are talking about the dynamic property access with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation):

```
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    // dynamic access here, destruct the object into your vars
    const {keyTermsArr, frequencyRef, ratingRef} = productDataObj[`prodType${prodType[i]}`];
```

Comment: This should be accepted as answer. I totally forgot that we can simply use a string for the property access, your answer reminded me why i love and hate js.

Answer (score 1):

While JavaScript doesn't directly support saving references to nested objects and arrays, here is a effective approach to achieve the desired behavior:

You can use Lodash's get Function for this.

```
import _ from 'lodash';

let keyTermsArrRef = _.get(productDataObj, `${productType}.keyTermsArr`);
keyTermsArrRef.push("more terms");
```

Note- you can also use libraries like Ramda for more powerful array and object manipulation functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply save the properties to an array. Not the best approach but i think this is concise enough:

```
let properties = []
for (const property in productDataObj) properties.push(property) ;
for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        keyTermsArrRef = productDataObj[properties[i]].keyTermsArr;
        frequencyRef = productDataObj[properties[i]].frequencyObj;
        ratingRef = productDataObj[properties[i]].ratingObj;
    }
```